# ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE automatically start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In my App I use ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE to record video.
But Now I have to start record when I start Activity.
How ro start ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and start recording automatically?
Or if it's impossible how to add listener to record button (ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) or check when this button was clicked?

Answer (score 2):

> How ro start ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and start recording automatically?

You don't. There is nothing in the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` protocol that allows you *request*, let alone *control*, how the third-party camera app allows the user to start and stop the video.

> how to add listener to record button (ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE) or check when this button was clicked?

I do not know what "record button" you are referring to. If you are referring to a button in the third-party camera app, there may not *be* a button. The third-party camera app may use a tap on the preview image, or a gesture, or a timer, or whatever the developer of the third-party camera app wants to do. Moreover, all of that is inside the third-party camera app, and you have no good way of finding out when those events occur, if at all.

If you need this level of control over video recording, *record the videos yourself* using `MediaRecorder`.

Comment: Ok. Next question. Can I check how long I use ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE? I have to check duration using ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE and duration saved video to check time difference.

Comment: @user1678400: "Can I check how long I use ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE?" -- well, you are welcome to note the time that you call `startActivityForResult()`, and the time when you are called with `onActivityResult()` with the response from the third-party camera app. However, bear in mind that the user is welcome to not return to you (e.g., press HOME) from the camera app.